# multiprocessing in python - what gets inherited by forkserver process from parent process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global, multiprocess

I am trying to use `forkserver` and I encountered `NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined` in worker processes.

I am using Python 3.6.4, but the documentation should be the same, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods it says that:

> The fork server process is single threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). **No unnecessary resources are inherited.**

Also, it says:

> Better to inherit than pickle/unpickle
>
> ***When using the spawn or **forkserver** start methods many types from multiprocessing need to be picklable so that child processes can use them***. However, one should generally avoid sending shared objects to other processes using pipes or queues. **Instead you should arrange the program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process.**

So apparently a key object that my worker process needs to work on did not get inherited by the server process and then passing to workers, why did that happen? I wonder what exactly gets inherited by forkserver process from parent process?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import multiprocessing
import (a bunch of other modules)

def worker_func(nameList):
    global largeObject
    for item in nameList:
        # get some info from largeObject using item as index
        # do some calculation
        return [item, info]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    largeObject # This is my large object, it's read-only and no modification will be made to it.
    nameList # Here is a list variable that I will need to get info for each item in it from the largeObject    
    ctx_in_main = multiprocessing.get_context('forkserver')
    print('Start parallel, using forking/spawning/?:', ctx_in_main.get_context())
    cores = ctx_in_main.cpu_count()
    with ctx_in_main.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(worker_func, nameList):
            result.append(x)
```

Thank you!

Best,

Comment: I tried splitting `nameList` to say 4 chunks and use zip([largeObject]*4, nameLis_splittedt) in `imap_unordered` and unwrap it later in `worker_func()`, this way it did get `largeObject` into workers, but it becomes super slow. I am guessing it's due to `largeObject`'s size.

Comment: Initialize large object before the worker function definition.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Can you clarify on how to initialize? `largeObject` here is a `NetworkX` object which came from a series of previous calculations  in `__main__ ` that involves reading large pandas df and other memory consuming operations.

Answer (score 10):

### Theory

Below is an excerpt from Bojan Nikolic [blog](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python/parallelism/2019/11/13/python-forkserver-preload.html)

> Modern Python versions (on Linux) provide three ways of starting the separate processes:
>
> 1. **Fork()**-ing the parent processes and continuing with the same processes image in both parent and child. This method is fast, but potentially unreliable when parent state is complex
> 2. **Spawning** the child processes, i.e., fork()-ing and then execv to replace the process image with a new Python process. This method is reliable but slow, as the processes image is reloaded afresh.
> 3. **The forkserver** mechanism, which consists of a separate Python server with that has a relatively simple state and which is fork()-ed when a new processes is needed. This method combines the speed of Fork()-ing with good reliability (because the parent being forked is in a simple state).

> #### Forkserver
>
> The third method, **forkserver**, is illustrated below. Note that children retain a copy of the forkserver state. This state is intended to be relatively simple, but it is possible to adjust this through the multiprocess API through the `set_forkserver_preload()` method.
> [image]

### Practice

Thus, if you want simething to be inherited by child processes from the parent, this must be specified in the **forkserver** state by means of `set_forkserver_preload(modules_names)`, which set list of module names to try to load in forkserver process. I give an example below:

```
# inherited.py
large_obj = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
```

```
# main.py
import multiprocessing
import os
from time import sleep

from inherited import large_obj


def worker_func(key: str):
    print(os.getpid(), id(large_obj))
    sleep(1)
    return large_obj[key]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    ctx_in_main = multiprocessing.get_context('forkserver')
    ctx_in_main.set_forkserver_preload(['inherited'])
    cores = ctx_in_main.cpu_count()
    with ctx_in_main.Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        for x in pool.imap(worker_func, ["one", "two", "three"]):
            result.append(x)
    for res in result:
        print(res)
```

Output:

```
# The PIDs are different but the address is always the same
PID=18603, obj id=139913466185024
PID=18604, obj id=139913466185024
PID=18605, obj id=139913466185024
```

And if we don't use preloading

```
...
    ctx_in_main = multiprocessing.get_context('forkserver')
    # ctx_in_main.set_forkserver_preload(['inherited']) 
    cores = ctx_in_main.cpu_count()
...
```

```
# The PIDs are different, the addresses are different too
# (but sometimes they can coincide)
PID=19046, obj id=140011789067776
PID=19047, obj id=140011789030976
PID=19048, obj id=140011789030912
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks so much for the answer. So I actually read Bojan's blog before, when I was trying to tackle the problem myself (surprisingly there aren't that many articles that touches on forkserver's methodology internally). I tried `set_forkserver_preload(large_object)` directly, naturally it didn't work :) I guess write a separate `.py` will work.

Comment: But the thing is, as I explained in question's comments, `large_object` here is a `NetworkX` object which came from a series of previous calculations in `__main__`  that involves reading large pandas df and other memory consuming operations. How can I modify that to work like your `inherited.py+main.py` setup here?

Comment: I am concerned that if I wrap all those operations that gets me `large_object` in the first place into a function and put it in `inherited.py` and `import inherited` and call the function, when I `set_forkserver_preload(['inherited'])`, forkserver will also get the unnecessary file descriptors and other things in parent's process, that will defeat my purpose here, I just want forkserver to inherite `large_object` along.

Comment: Try to move these calculations to the inherited module so that they happen when the server imports it

Comment: I see what you are suggesting... I guess if I put those calculations directly into `inherited.py`, it will be executed *twice* (once when I imported the module and the other when server imports it), this might work if I just want a single-threaded safe process that workers can fork from. But here I am trying to get workers to not inherite uncessary resources and **only** get `large_object`. And I don't think putting those calculations in `__main__` in `inherited.py` will work either, since now none of the processes will execute them including main and server.

Comment: As I know ‘fork’ essentially snapshots all of the memory space of the parent process, and it is impossible to do this for a specific object. Maybe fork server is not the right approach for your task

Comment: I see, your points are valid. I guess forkserver is more about 'safe forks'. If the goal here is to get workers to inherite minimal resources, I am better off separating my code into 2, do the calculation first, pickle it, exit the interpreter, and start a fresh one to load the pickled `large_object` and just go nuts with either `fork` or `forkserver`.

Answer (score 3):

So after an inspiring discussion with Alex I think I have sufficient info to address my question: what exactly gets inherited by forkserver process from parent process?

Basically when the server process starts, it will import your main module and everything before `if __name__ == '__main__'` will be executed. That's why my code don't work, because `large_object` is nowhere to be found in `server` process and in all those worker processes that fork from the **`server` process**.

Alex's solution works because `large_object` now gets imported to both main and server process so every worker forked from server will also gets `large_object`. If combined with `set_forkserver_preload(modules_names)` all workers might even get the **same** `large_object` from what I saw. The reason for using `forkserver` is explicitly explained in Python documentations and in Bojan's blog:

> When the program starts and selects the forkserver start method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and requests that it fork a new process. **The fork server process is single threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary resources are inherited**.
>
> The forkserver mechanism, which consists of a separate Python server with that has a relatively simple state and which is fork()-ed when a new processes is needed. **This method combines the speed of Fork()-ing with good reliability (because the parent being forked is in a simple state)**.

So it's more on the safe side of concern here.

On a side note, if you use `fork` as the starting method though, you don't need to import anything since all child process gets a copy of parents process memory (or a reference if the system use COW-`copy-on-write`, please correct me if I am wrong). In this case using `global large_object` will get you access to `large_object` in `worker_func` directly.

The `forkserver` might not be a suitable approach for me because the issue I am facing is memory overhead. All the operations that gets me `large_object` in the first place are memory-consuming, so I don't want any unnecessary resources in my worker processes.

If I put all those calculations directly into `inherited.py` as Alex suggested, it will be executed *twice* (once when I imported the module in main and once when the server imports it; maybe even more when worker processes were born?), this is suitable if I just want a single-threaded safe process that workers can fork from. But since I am trying to get workers to not inherit unnecessary resources and only get `large_object`, this won't work.
And putting those calculations in `__main__` in `inherited.py` won't work either since now none of the processes will execute them, including main and server.

So, as a conclusion, if the goal here is to get workers to inherit minimal resources, I am better off breaking my code into 2, do `calculation.py` first, pickle the `large_object`, exit the interpreter, and start a fresh one to load the pickled `large_object`. Then I can just go nuts with either `fork` or `forkserver`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem 100% but if the only problem is executing the memory-heavy calculations twice you can get around that with admittedly some dirty hacking: The import of the module is only needed so you don't get a large_object is not defined" error. But you could set `large_object` in `inherited.py` to None for the initial import and only really import `large_object` when `set_forkserver_preload()` is called, e.g. by writing some value to a tmp config file in your main and checking that value in `inherited.py` to decide whether to actually load large_object or not.